# MySQL get % of dates from TIMESTAMP Column for google LineChart

Tags: mysql, sql

I basically created a social network site and im building a dashboard to show me various info on the site. I want a line chart showing me when the most members joined according to the date in their timestamp column which is specified when they register. I am a bit stumped as the mysql I currently have doesnt give me the desired results, it instead gives me the date for every record and a percentage beside it in the 'pct' label

```
        SELECT DATE_FORMAT(joinedDate , "%d/%m/%Y"),COUNT(*) *
            t.factor AS pct
        FROM 
            first_reg
        JOIN (
        SELECT 100 / COUNT(*) AS factor
        FROM first_reg
        ) AS t
        GROUP BY
            joinedDate
```

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer

```
    SELECT COUNT(DATE(`joinedDate`)) AS `no_of_members_on_this_day`,
                                         DATE(`joinedDate`) AS `date_of_signup` 
                            FROM   tableName 
                            JOIN (
                                    SELECT 100 / COUNT(*) AS factor
                                    FROM tableName
                                  ) AS t
                            GROUP BY 
                                DATE(`joinedDate`)
```